# Cordova/Phonehap - get app version number from config.xml

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I know there are a lot of topics on this issue but none of them seem to have the solution I need.

In this framework7 / phonegap app where I'm working on there is this send feedback option in which I want to include the appversion. I tried a lot of plugins to get the versionnumber from the config.xml file but none of them seem to work so I might be on the wrong path.

Currently I have [cordova-plugin-app-version](https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version) installed and I'm trying to alert the versionnumber as a test.

```
$$(document).on('click', '.do-send-feedback', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber().then(function (version) {
      alert(version);
  });
});
```

I've also tried (but that didn't work either):

```
cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber(function (version) {
    alert(version);
});
```

The code seems to get stuck at that point and I don't know why. The plugin in installed and specified in config.xml

The only thing I did different was changing 'cordova' to ' phongegap' in the installation since otherwise it won't work. but I'm always doing it that way and never had problems with that in particular before.

Testing it on my Android device.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [wizUtils plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-wizUtils) will work for Android and iOS.

Install it:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-wizUtils#develop --nofetch
```

Use it:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
    wizUtils.getBundleVersion(function(version){
        alert("Version: " + version);
    }); 
}, false);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't give me any result as well. I'm afraid there is another problem but don't know what.. :(

Comment: If I were you, I'd create a standalone test app to validate this: the above works fine in isolation. Maybe something else in your app code is causing the JS not to run. I would connect Chrome Dev Tools to the WebView and remote debug it.

Comment: I can't get my app to work in the browser so it's kind of a try and catch thing. Gonna try to fix that first

Comment: `I can't get my app to work in the browser` - this is a native plugin for Android and iOS so won't work in the browser enviroment (as many other plugins do not).

Comment: I understand that. I'll test that part on my phone. what I mean is that the whole app doesn't work in the browser. This is not caused by the version but it is a cordovaplugin. I'm gonna fix that first and than I'll have a better understanding of what is going wrong and will report that back here

Comment: The problem was that I was testing it in the phonegap app. You need to make a build in order to make it work. Thanks for the answer